# synchronizing history when ipython notebook and console are connected to the same kernel

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have `ipython notebook` running on a remote server, i.e.

```
ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

which I access from my local machine. Further, I ssh to the remote server from my machine, and start ipython console (terminal) on that server. I have found following command to work well:

```
ipython console --existing \
~/.config/ipython/profile_nbserver/security/kernel-*.json
```

Now I am connected to the same remote kernel from two different clients (lets call them `browser` and `terminal`). Everything works well, except one annoying detail:

1) in `browser`, I type `a=1`

2) in `terminal`, I type `b=2`

3) in both clients I can see both commands using `%history`. But when I want to cycle through the history (in `terminal`) using <kbd>Up</kbd>, it only shows the commands which have been typed in the terminal, (i.e `b=2`). Similarly, I am unable to use `a` + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> in the terminal, to go back in history and find the command starting with `a`.

From what I understand, my two clients are using two separate history files `history.sqlite`. But why does `%history` show all commands ?

**Question:** 
Is there any way to configure using one `history.sqlite` for both  clients ?

I find, having easy access to history is absolutely crucial. Moreover, I see using both terminal and browser as complementary, they both have tradeoffs and are best used combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set where the history gets loaded either by setting it at the terminal:

```
ipython --HistoryManager.hist_file=$HOME/ipython_hist.sqlite
```

or within the ipython config files:

```
import os
c.HistoryManager.hist_file=os.path.expanduser("~/ipython_hist.sqlite")
```

Comment: and will the history database handle access from two clients concurrently ?

Comment: I'm guessing they are going to clobber each other actually, since it's one sqlite file... Might as well try it out and see what happens though!

Comment: and how come `%history` shows complete history in both clients?